# Display each XML attribute separately

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a small issue trying to display each attibute seperetly when I play it, it seems to display all the attributes in title.  I thought you could sort of take the same approach as you do with arrays by writing something like

```
listView1.Items.Add(items[0]);
```

I am completly new to this so i apoligize if the question sounds noobish.

xml file:

```
<books>
  <type>
    <price>2.50</price>
    <title>Harry</title>
  </type>
  <type>
    <price>2.70</price>
    <title>bob</title>
  </type>
</books>
```

Code:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("XMLfile1.xml");
XmlNodeType type;

while(reader.Read())
{
  type = reader.NodeType;
  if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
  {
    if (reader.Name == "title")
    {
      reader.Read();
      listView1.Items.Add(reader.Value);
    }
  }
}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: I highly recommend looking into XDocument instead of XmlTextReader. I use it for everything XML related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"XMLfile1.xml");
foreach (var titleElement in document.Descendants("title"))
{
    listView1.Items.Add(titleElement.Value);
}
```

or alternatively:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"XMLfile1.xml");
foreach (var titleElement in document.Root.Elements("type").Select(x => x.Element("title")))
{
    listView1.Items.Add(titleElement.Value);
}
```

Comment: the 1st code does the same thing then i posted and displays all attributes, and the other code does not display anything but thanx for trying

Comment: with the xml supplied, what is the output you're hoping for exactly?